# fastapi/sqlmodel creates id column as having the last ordinal position if table class inherits from base class

Tags: postgresql, fastapi, sqlmodel

Let's say my `schemas.py` looks like these:

```
class EimBase(SQLModel):
    fimno: Optional[str]
    spv_component_id: Optional[int] 
    eim_technology_name: Optional[str]
    eim_technology_version: Optional[str]
    obsolete_start_date: Optional[date]
    actual_remediation_date: Optional[date]
    intended_remediation_date: Optional[date]
    issuestatus: Optional[str]
    current_manu_phase: Optional[str]
    current_manu_phase_start: Optional[date]
    current_manu_phase_end: Optional[date]
    remediation_type: Optional[str]
    issue_component_id: Optional[str]
    middleware_instance_name: Optional[str]

class Eim(EimBase,table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None,primary_key=True)
    spv_component_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None,index=True)
```

When the database creates the table it will create like that in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE stage_eim (
        fimno VARCHAR,
        spv_component_id INTEGER,
        eim_technology_name VARCHAR,
        eim_technology_version VARCHAR,
        obsolete_start_date DATE,
        actual_remediation_date DATE,
        intended_remediation_date DATE,
        issuestatus VARCHAR,
        current_manu_phase VARCHAR,
        current_manu_phase_start DATE,
        current_manu_phase_end DATE,
        remediation_type VARCHAR,
        issue_component_id VARCHAR,
        middleware_instance_name VARCHAR,
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

As you can see the id has the last position. I want the id to be the first position:

```
CREATE TABLE stage_eim (
            id SERIAL NOT NULL,
....
)
```

How can I achieve that while keeping my schemas with the same structure ? If I define `Eim` on top of `EimBase` it will complain about `spv_component_id`

Comment: A bit of a hack, but how about having a mixin-class named `HasId` that has the single id field, then `class Eim(HasId, EimBase, table=True):`?

Comment: yep, that's hacky, no other way ? usually an id should have first positional ordering

Comment: Why does it matter, in what order the columns are defined? Column order has no semantic meaning in database tables aside from a few edge cases.